# Making a capturing regex repeat

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex `\[\[(.+)\]\]`. I use it to capture wikilinks like `hey I [[am]] so awesome` (captures `am`). How could I modify this so that `hey I [[am]] more [[awesome]] than you think` yields both `am` and `awesome`, separately? My attempts have yielded single strings like `am]] more [[awesome`. A little context: I'm using this to write a Ruby IRC bot.

P.S. Wikilinks can also be multi-word, like `hey I am much [[more awesome]] than you [[probably think]].`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the `.+` non-greedy:

```
\[\[(.+?)\]\]
```

See this reference: [ruby regexen](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#12).

Comment: I could swear I had tried that. For reference, isn't it common to use the term "lazy"? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Not for regex (that I am aware of). It's greedy vs. non-greedy. Lazy is more for things that get evaluated "later" (or never) rather than on the spot they are declared/first mentionned.

Comment: Kudu, lazy or non-greedy. They are both correct and descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

You might use a non-greedy version, e.g. `\[\[(.+?)\]\]` (note the question mark).

Answer (score 4):

String's [scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) operators should work to capture everything the regex you are looking for is `/\[\[([^\]])+\]\]/` the `[\]]+` being key. that will match through until the first `]` and stop.

```
string.scan( /\[\[([^\]])+\]\]/ );
```